# injected javascript not always working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I m trying to develop a chrome extension for twitter. And I encounter this problem and tried everything I could find online, but still did not solve the problem.

Here is the detailed explanation.

I user content_scripts to inject own js code to manipulate the divs on the twitter web page.

Source code is like this:

manifest.json

```
   "content_scripts": [ { 
      "js": [ "jquery.js", "code.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*.twitter.com/*", "https://*.twitter.com/*" ]
   } ],
```

code.js

```
function JSCode()
{  
/* my own jquery code here */
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var node = document.createElement('script');
var toInject = "("+JSCode.toString()+")();";

node.innerText = toInject ;
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(node);
});
```

And I debug the source code twitter page,

```
<script>/*my own jquery code here */</script>
</body>
```

is always at bottom of body tag.

If I just type twitter.com or twitter.com/user_name in chrome address bar, hit and go, the javascript works fine.

If I am already on twitter.com webpage(js code works when 1st time loading webpage), I click my own profile link and redirects to my own twitter page, which will be in the same chrome web page,the javascript seems not being executed(though the js code is still appended at bottom of body), only Reload the whole web page will make the javascript work again.

Any advices on why it is this and how can I resolve this? Thank you

Comment: When you click your profile link, does the address in the address bar change ? If aeverything is loaded dymanicaly (say through AJAX), then the code will not execute again. So, you'll have to find other methods. (It might help us come up with something, if we knew what your JSCode does.)

Comment: Thank you @ExpertSystem. <br>
This is a [demo code](http://d.pr/f/t4tV) I just uploaded. <br>
If you download and load it as unpacked extension, then go to https://twitter.com using chrome, you will notice user name of each twitter accounts becomes red color. Now, click your own profile at left upper corner, and chrome will redirects you to https://twitter.com/username , you will notice this time, tweet accounts username didnt become red. But if you just right click and reload the page, user name becomes red color again.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have a twitter account to check it myself :/ Some remarks: 1. Seems like you can remove the `"background"` altogether from your manifest. 2. You don't need all that `<script>` creating voodoo stuff in `code.js`: `$(document).ready(function(){JSCode();});` is enough. 3. It might be the case that you are not getting the `document.ready` event, because your script is by default injected at "document_idle". Try injecting at "document_start" and see what happens.

Comment: (Yet, like I already said in my first comment, it could be because of dynamic loading of content - someone with a twitter account could check it out. Or you can watch the `Network` tab in the console and see what kind of traffic is generated by your clicking the profile name.)

Comment: Thank you @ExpertSystem , to reply your comment: 1. yes, it is not necessary for this demo 2. yes, indeed, JSCode() is enough 3. I added `run_at` `document_start` within content_script and it still behaviours the same as before. Yes, I agree with you it might have something to do with dynamic loading, I am still trying to figure out why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Ctrl+Shift+j - this will bring up the console and show you any script errors. You should easily be able to narrow it down from there. (or go to the chrome 3 bar menu thing in the top right Tools-->JavaScript Console)

If you're using jQuery you might as well do this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append($('<script>').html('('+JSCode.toString()+')();'));
});
```

...So what we discovered is that the code inside JSCode was being loaded and running fine... However as new elements were being added to the document the CSS was not 'magically' being applied to them (of course this is how it's supposed to be). Adding a new  element to the head of the document with the desired changes in it stayed persistent to all newly created elements across the entire document... I'll show the good example first followed by the way that didn't work as hoped...

```
$('head').append($('<style>.fullname { color: red; border: 2px dotted green; }</style>'));
```

The following didn't work so well in this dynamically loading page...

```
$(".fullname").css({color:"red", border:"2px dotted green"});
```

Comment: If it doesn't work you might have to change it to $('body').append($($('<script>').html('('+JSCode.toString()+')();')));
but idk... let us know...

Comment: Thank you JxAxMxIxN
 both my method and your method works the first time when the page loads. the problem is, lets say, when I click my user profile and redirects my profile page, the javascript injected still append at bottom of body tag(which is expected), BUT seems the code is not executed.. If go javascript console and check, there is no error. I suspect is related to chrome event listener(for instance the js code works when create a new tab or click reload), but it did not take affect when redirect to same web links matches twitter.com

Comment: Why are you trying to inject this code anyhow? Is the code coming to you via Ajax or something? You should have free run and access to everything and anything you want without having to inject anything if you're using a chrome script...

for unlimited web resource access permission - add  "web_accessible_resources": ["\*"]
and add "http://\*/\*","https://\*/\*" to your permissions section in your script manifest.json file

Comment: This is a [demo code](http://d.pr/f/t4tV) I just uploaded. 
If you download and load it as unpacked extension, then go to https://twitter.com using chrome, you will notice user name of each twitter accounts becomes red color. Now, click your own profile at left upper corner, and chrome will redirects you to https://twitter.com/username , you will notice this time, tweet accounts username didnt become red. But if you just right click and reload the page, user name becomes red color again.
please let me know if you have any thoughts about this

Comment: Put this in your JSCode() function instead
$('head').append($('<style>.fullname { color: red; border: 2px dotted green; }</style>')); it slightly clears the issue... more to come...

Comment: So what was happening is $(".fullname").css({color:"red"}); adds the css to all currently created elements with the "fullname" class when it initially runs - and when new elements are created they don't magically inherit this css. By adding the css to a <style> tag in the document header it stays persistent across the entire page. Now on to the next problem =)

Comment: Thank you @JxAxMxIxN !, yes, your solution solves all related css issues, Brilliant! 
I got one more question, what if in my js code, have something like `$(".fullname").remove()` ? which cant be solved by css method. Do you happen to know any method bypass this?

Comment: perhaps you could add an id to that newly created style $('head').append($('<style>.fullname { color: red; border: 2px dotted green; }</style>').attr('id','fullname-style')); then replace its innerHTML with a blank string when you want to clear it $('#fullname-style').html(""); - will have to test it...

Comment: Hi @JxAxMxIxN I tried you code exactly as mentioned in the post
`$('head').append($('<style>.fullname { color: red; border: 2px dotted green; }</style>').attr('id','fullname-style')); $('#fullname-style').html("");` seems it does not work on my side. I tried `  $('head').append($('<style>.fullname { color: red; border: 2px dotted green; }</style>')); 
  $(.fullname).html("");` as well. Same as before, the js code only executes when first time loading the page or try to reload the page, while the css code you mentioned works totally fine as always.

Comment: I m asking the js part is because the extension I wrote have quite a bit part code is like `preprend, removeClass, appendTo`, eg. to rearrange the div

Comment: @air_bob: It might be worth looking into **[MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)** and handle any DOM changes appropriately. Depending on your exact setup it might be an overkill though...

Comment: To conclude this question, eventually I only injected css to the webpage, since the injected javascript will take time to take affect since twitter rendering its contents, that will make the extension not that user friendly. Here is the final extension I made: http://pretweetify.com

Comment: I'm a tad confused at what you're trying to accomplish a couple posts up - but if you want to remove that style element later - using $('#fullname-style').remove() should do the trick and clear it completely from the head (you'll have to then completely add it again to apply a different style). Glad you got it working though!